# Hiding ItemTemplate Controls within Formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

Currently my code is hiding certain `Panel`(s) contained within the `ItemTemplate` of a `FormView` dependent on the Users Role(s).

The current solution: `((Panel)FormView1.FindControl("pnlIsAdmin")).Visible = IsAdmin;`

The problem is that this code can't be run until the Formview has been completed `.Databind();`

Now I don't know much about FormViews, but surely there's a way for me to hide controls such as the panel above in a better place, and NOT dependent on `.Databind();` ( like on page Load )??

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually like mixing my code-behind & display pages, but you could just wrap the control in some server tags:

```
<% if(isAdmin){ %> <asp:Panel ID="pnlIsAdmin" runat="server"></asp:Panel> <% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for a working answer, actually much better then where I was going.